# How to position regularly-spaced arrows along line with Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I'm using Geoserver 2.6.2. I would like the arrows I've positionned on linear features to be regularly spaced. The fact is that what appears as a line is in fact composed of several lines of different length.

When I position an arrow mark on the centroid of each line feature, the marks are not regularly spaced and appearence is not good (see below). Is there a way to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to merge your lines together (and probably fix the directions too) before you can do this.

Comment: OK, thanks @iant ! You could put your comment in an answer so that I could accept it...